# GAOL origin isn't English

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

If the origin is French and the British have adapted it, why would they claim America corrupted the so-called English version if it wasn't theirs to begin with? And why must a simple word like jail appear as goal, misspelled?

Comment: As a note, *goal* and *gaol* are not the same word—so neither is a misspelling of the other. That would be similar to saying that only one of *to*, *two*, and *too* is spelled correctly, and that the others are misspellings.

Comment: Hi Goldie. Your question as stated is a bit unclear and opinion-based. Who is the "they" that is claiming the 'corruption' - do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 1):

Like many words in British English Gaol entered the language as part of the aftermath of the Norman Conquest in 1066.

Gaol in British English is derived from the Anglo-Norman French word "Gayole" rather than the Old French " Jailoe".

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jail)

> Origin
>   Middle English: based on Latin cavea (see cage). The word came into English in two forms, jaiole from Old French and gayole from Anglo-Norman French gaole (surviving in the spelling gaol), originally pronounced with a hard g, as in goat.

But in Britain you will see both forms used "jail" and "gaol" very few people would claim an Amerucan corruption of the word.

Comment: For an American "corruption", see **hoosegow**.